# JSON with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

Someone please help with this!!!

I'm trying to simply parse my json object in javascript within rails, and NOTHING seems to work.

The story is in the controller is:

```
def map 
    @nodes = Node.all
    @json = {"Nodes" => @nodes.as_json(:only => [:ID, :Lat, :Lon])}
end
```

In my view, I have simple javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stuff = <%= @json %>;
var json = JSON.parse(stuff);
alert("text");
</script>
```

I'm just trying to see if the code runs through the first two lines with alert message, but it never works, always throwing me a unexpected token error (usually a colon or a { ). I've also tried doing the eval method, but that also doesn't work. Can someone please help me parse the json in the javascript? I would be eternally grateful....

Answer (score 1):

you can go with your current approach, there are few correction that you need to make it work

@json is not a json here, its a hash and when you assign it to javascript variable it looks like

`stuff = {"Nodes" => node value}` here **=>** is not accepted in javascript, thus its not a valid json object.

you need to convert hash object in json like

```
var stuff = <%= @json.to_json %>;
```

Comment: Hi Naren, I tried that in my code, and it gives me an unexpected token error if I try to inspect the element in Google Chrome. Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html The rendering json section.

```
render :json => @nodes
```

Comment: How does render pass the json to the view? I though I just need an instance variable and I can simply access that from the view?